# control a users USB device via a webpage? Possible?

Tags: asp.net, controls, usb, device

I'm wondering if there is a way to create an asp.net webpage that will connect a visitors USB device to an application on the windows bases server?  This way we avoid having to install a software on the visitors computer to control a USB device update that they purchase form us.

All they have to do is visit our update page, plug their deivce to the USB, and have our site update the usb hardware.

Possible? or am I dreaming? :)

i found software like:  USB over IP, and few others.  But not show ure its possible to create a C# or vb.net based ASP.net page to control the visitors USB device.

Please advise.

Comment: Ford (Sync) is doing it for their updates... but I think it installs an ActiveX app (like I see below). https://secure.syncmyride.com/Own/Modules/UserManagement/Login.aspx

Comment: Definitely possible Garmin Connect manages this on their web page through some sort of plugin.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Web pages and scripts that run in browsers are limited in what local system resources they can access.  Direct access to hardware like USB devices has obvious security implications.

The only way I can think of to do this might be an [ActiveX control](http://www.microsoft.com/protect/terms/activex.aspx) (IE only, I think) or some other kind of browser plugin.

Comment: haha. funny that the "only thing we can think of" are two separate technologies.  lol

Comment: Though Java really is "some other kind of browser plugin".

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: LOL, I noticed that coincidence, too.  @Anon: True.

Comment: ActiveX is restricted to IE only (as you noted) where as JAVA can be used on any browser except for Chrome (afaik) - (note Java support for Chrome is currently in Beta.)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is building a webserver into the USB device. Give the device internet access, and get it to download its own firmware in a process controlled through the webpage that the usb device serves.

Note that I have no idea if this is actually possible, just thought I'd throw in this different way of looking at the problem.

Comment: Interesting concept.  Basically create a web server that has an API.  A good example of this is XBMC (http://www.xbmc.org) where you can control the entire software (including adding and removing files, renaming, etc) via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can possibly imagine doing this is through [JAVA](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/j-usb.html)

EDIT: Looks like there might be an [ActiveX](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/iewebdevelopment/thread/e613f898-a18a-47e7-81bc-5a959ec2db06) way to do this as well, though ActiveX is Internet Explorer only, which limits it's usability.

Comment: Sorry to nit-pick, but Java is not an acronym and shouldn't be all caps.  Just a little pet peeve of mine.  :)  http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/faq.html

Comment: MMM... don't really care how I typed it... the point is still the same

Comment: check this out

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIZqmXfrRLI

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create an ActiveX/.NETcontrol/Java Applet that will do it.

Granting the rights to this thing to access local devices will require certain security setup which can be automated, but in any case will require some user consent/interaction

Answer (score 1):

I see here 2 ways:

1. *ActiveX* control

   The problem is that the user should first download and install the
   ActiveX from an Internet web server or from a local file
2. *USB* Device driver + *DHCP* Server + Web server embedded in the
   device

   Your *USB* device, once plugged, should present itself as a "Virtual
   Ethernet Interface" in order for Windows to add the driver to the
   list of the Internet Connections.

   The Device should have also a DHCP server in order to give Windows
   an IP address. Beware of the fact

   The USB Device should also have an HTTP server.

   At the end of this process, Windows will have 2 IP addresses.

   Now you have to figure out how to have IE point to the index.html
   file of the device.
3. Buy/Find a commercial software

   You are not the first guy on this planet that has similar
   requirements.